# Ubuntu 16.04 screen tearing intel i5 ivybridge

Tags: graphics, intel, tearing

im new to the linux world, come from windows and lately mac :-)
I am from germany, i hope you can understand me^^
I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS and it feels great so far.

My system details:
Intel® Core™ i5-3470 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 4
Intel® Ivybridge Desktop
64-bit

Im fighting with "screen tearing" while watching videos in firefox / sometimes while scrolling pages and with the ubuntu video player. It is mostly in fast scenes. It is like there is a square.
I have tried the following:

/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d
20-intel.conf

Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "intel"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection

Software & Updates: using processor microcode firmware for intel cpus from intel-microcode (proprietary)
But there is still tearing :-(
I hope you can help me, i will figth till i won :-)
I dont want to go back to windows, linux is the future and i like the console very much. Feels like ms dos from the past good times :-)  Thank you & with best regards porkii

Answer (score 1):

This is answered in the post referenced below. In short the Xorg config files now live in /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/{nn-name.conf} e.g. /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf.

Moving your config file to this location (with su/sudo) should resolve your problem after you restart Xorg. [Reboot/Save your work then sudo killall Xorg etc]. It worked for me on a Lenovo T430.

see: [Intel integrated graphics screen tearing](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708855/intel-integrated-graphics-screen-tearing)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/684881)

Comment: @Pilot6: Simon already summarises the crucial info in his answer.