# Screen tearing on XPS13 9310, Ubuntu 20.04, Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe]

Tags: 20.04, xorg, dell, screen, intel

I know there are many questions regarding this problem, but no solution I have found so far seems to help me with this issue.

This is a brand new Dell XPS 9310 with Intel graphics and Ubuntu 20.04. I have screen tearing every now and then. The following solutions did not work:

1. Switching to Wayland. This helped everything look a bit smoother, but after a short while I noticed the screen tearing still occur.
2. Adding various potential contents into `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` or to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel-graphics.conf`. For example, I tried the solution proposed in https://askubuntu.com/a/1237079/221347, the one in https://askubuntu.com/a/1237079/221347 and some other I have found across the web. Some did not make any difference, some really destroyed the entire visualization.
3. I tried to use `compton`. It did not make any difference (or perhaps I did not use it properly).
4. I disabled animations in `gnome-tweaks`.
5. I switched from Ubuntu to gnome, to gnome-classic and to gnome-xorg.

---

Here is some potential relevant info on my system.

```
bach@pita::~$ inxi -G
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
  Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.13 driver: fbdev 
  unloaded: modesetting,vesa resolution: 1920x1200~60Hz 
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3
```

and

```
bach@pita::~$ sudo lshw | grep display -A12
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: TigerLake-LP GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             logical name: /dev/fb0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list fb
             configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1200 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1200
             resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:146 memory:6052000000-6052ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.

```
bach@pita::~$ uname -a
Linux pita 5.13.0-25-generic #26~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jan 7 16:27:40 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

### Update

I've edited `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` as follows:

```
Section "Device"
   Identifier  "Intel Graphics"
   Driver      "i915"
   Option "AccelMethod" "sna"
   Option "DRI" "3"
   Option "TearFree" "true"
EndSection
```

This almost stopped screen tearing, but scrolling is still shaky, and tearing occurs every once in a while.

### Screencast

[Here's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBZwD.jpg) a quick screencast showing a very minor tearing that occurs with this configuration.

### Quick update

Wayland does not fix screen tearing, but it does change its behavior.
For example, in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MfL_JkcEFbE), I do not see the tearing anymore. I do notice when scrolling (Firefox, say), when alt-tab, etc., it seems like part of the window is being drawn a bit too late.

I also feel that the fans work less when I'm on Wayland.

### Update: ubuntu-drivers

When trying `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` I get `No drivers found for installation.`.

### Update: xserver-xorg-video-intel

This package is not currently installed. The output of `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel` is empty.

Comment: Try `Option "DRI" "2"` instead of  `Option "DRI" "3"` https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Intel_graphics#Troubleshooting

Comment: Did you try `sudo ubuntu-drivers install`? Something relevant on `journalctl -xef`? If so, please add it to the post.

Comment: Are yiou using a monitor or a TV and what connection between the PC and the screen is being utilised?

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel` please.

Comment: I am not using any monitor or a TV. I am with my laptop's screen.

Comment: what is the output of `dpkg-query --show --showformat='${db:Status-Status}\n' linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`?

Comment: The output is `installed`.

Answer (score 0):

Add below lines to     `nano ~/.drirc`

```
<device screen="0" driver="dri2">
    <application name="Default">
        <option name="vblank_mode" value="0"/>
    </application>
</device>
```

and replace `Option "DRI" "3"` with `Option "DRI" "2"` in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

More info: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Intel_graphics#Troubleshooting

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately, there's no visible change. Using Xorg, there's still constant tearing. Using Wayland, there are still screen lags.

Comment: Would you try to add this `Option "TripleBuffer" "true"` to `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf` too?

Comment: I tried that as well.